# How can I prevent a cat from scratching the top of his head?

Tags: cats, injury, scratching

My cat has a wound on top of his head and keeps scratching it with his hind claws.

He keeps getting the soft cone collar off even though it is tied tightly and knotted.  How can I keep this collar on.  How can I prevent him from scratching at the top of his head?

Answer (score 1):

You might try making a padded cloth cap with a collar. He might still get it off as easily as the cone collar but there's still a chance he won't. Or you might try using nail caps. They might still do some damage to the wound if it hasn't scabbed properly but at least they're not sharp.